# How to see FormData key values pairs in Angular DevTools

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome-devtools

I try to understand a legacy code in Angular.

```
formData.append('fileA', this.fileA);
```

I just want to see the values when I debug using the DevTools.

I put a breakpoint and opened the devtools and tried to watch the variable. This is what exists, how I can see actually the keys and values when I debug via the devtools?

[image]

Comment: You _call the methods_ to get access to the values, e.g. to see the value(s) for a particular form control you call `.get(name)`.

Comment: Use `[...formData]` or `Object.fromEntries(formData)`

Comment: not understand, can you please provide more information? how can I see in the dev tools? do I need to write a new code? can you please provide any example